# Editing a Concrete5 site we inherited from another company

Tags: content-management-system, concrete5

Our company recently took a job where the customer is using a Concrete5 site.  They want some minor changes to the site.

Upon thoroughly examining the site, we find ourselves UNABLE to make any edits to the Custom Blocks that are installed.  We come from a MODX background and used to being able to edit chunks and backend code.

Can someone let me know which section or areas we should be looking in?  Or have they somehow locked it all up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Concrete5 is definitely not locked up -- it's actually one of the easier PHP CMS's to modify (once you know the lay of the land of course). If it's custom blocks you want to edit, they will be located in one of two places:

- SITEROOT/blocks/block_handle/...
- SITEROOT/packages/package_handle/blocks/block_handle/...

(substitute "block_handle" with the lowercase_underscore name of the block, and "package_handle" with the lowercase_underscore name of the package -- most likely the same as the block handle)

If you want to ask a more specific question -- e.g. how do you make a specific customization to a specific piece of functionality for a specific block -- you will probably be better off asking in the Concrete5 forums (http://concrete5.org/community/forums). It's still a relatively small community compared to the other PHP CMS's and frameworks, but people are very helpful and non-trollish there.